# MySQL algorithm to update bank transaction (final balance)

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, sql-update, subquery

I am still new to MySQL and currently working on a problem to update final balance in the bank transaction. I were given the following table to begin with. [The given table named as "transaction"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1Wp9.png)

I am expected to give the following results;
[The expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wU0HA.png)

I managed to work on the ***credit_balance*** column, thru the following MySQL code;

```
UPDATE transaction 
SET credit_debit = CASE money_in_or_out 
                    WHEN "OUT" THEN amount*(-1)
                    ELSE amount*(1)
                   END;
                   
ALTER TABLE `sql_invoicing`.`transaction` 
CHANGE COLUMN `credit_debit` `credit_debit` DECIMAL(9,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL ;
```

As for the ***balance*** column, I only manage wrote the following;

```
UPDATE transaction 
SET balance = 
(SELECT balance + credit_debit
ORDER BY payment_id DESC
LIMIT 1);
```

which yield the following results which are wrong; [The returned result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lfjsi.png)

Hence could anyone give any suggestion to deal this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Typically, you would maintain the balance as part of the account table, not as part of your transaction table. If you want to store the balance after every transaction, then I would calculate this as part of the application logic as opposed to sql. It is basically calculated as taking the bakance after the previous transaction and adding or subtracting the value of the current transaction.

Comment: @Shadow Hi, I don't really mind about the account nor the transaction table (it just a dummy data btw) since the ultimate objective here is for me to get the idea on how to write algorithm to update bank transaction since I am new to MySQL (just started less than 3 weeks ago). However, I would always keep in mind about that as I progress. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are describing a window sum.

As a starter: I would not recommend storing such information, because it is tedious to maintain. Instead, you can compute it on the flyw when needed, or put the logic in a view.

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can just use window functions:

```
select t.*,
    sum(case when money_in_or_out = 'OUT' then - amount else amount end) 
        over(order by payment_id) as balance
from transaction t
```

In earlier versions, you can use a correlated subquery instead:

```
select t.*,
    (
        select sum(case when money_in_or_out = 'OUT' then - amount else amount end)
        from transaction t1
        where t1.payment_id <= t.payment_id
    ) as balance
from transaction t
```

Note: one might expect a bank to have more that one customer. Your table should have a column to store that information, so the balance can be computed *per customer*. You would then modify the window function as follows:

```
    sum(case when money_in_or_out = 'OUT' then - amount else amount end) 
        over(partition by customer_id order by payment_id) as balance
```

And the subquery would become:

```
    (
        select sum(case when money_in_or_out = 'OUT' then - amount else amount end)
        from transaction t1
        where t1.customer_id = t.customer_id and t1.payment_id <= t.payment_id
    ) as balance
```

Comment: Nope, account balances are typically one of the classic exceptions that you store because over the time it will be very difficult to calculate them every time you want to check if you can make a transaction or if the customer wants to view the balance. However, the balance is typically stored in the the account table, not in the transaction table. If you store it in the transaction table, it will show you the balance after the transaction - which would not change, since if a transaction is done, then it is final.

Comment: @Shadow: I see your point. Don’t you think, however, than an answer would be more helpful than multiple comments and downvotes (assuming that the latter are yours)?